# how to get array of sturct from another contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract  createstuduim {
    
  struct   studuim  {
    string  name ;
    uint id ;
    uint price ;
    address payable addr ;
    string location ;
    uint cap ;
    uint day ;
    uint time ;
    bool [][][] resv;
    
  }

  studuim []   public studuims ;
    
  event addstudium_event (string  _name,uint _id , uint _price ,address payable _address ,string _location ,uint _cap ,uint _day ,uint _time );

  function addstrudtuim (string memory _name,uint _id ,uint _price ,address payable _address ,string memory _location ,uint _cap ,uint _day ,uint _time,bool [][][] memory resv ) public  {
     
    studuims.push(studuim(_name,_id,_price,_address,_location,_cap,_day,_time,resv));
     
    emit addstudium_event(_name,_id,_price, _address ,_location,_cap,_day,_time) ;
  }
    
}
```

contract 2 :

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "./createstuduim.sol" ;
import "./jnbez_coin.sol";

contract user is createstuduim, jnbez_coin {
   
   function compareStrings(string memory a, string memory b) public view returns (bool) {
        return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked((b))));
   }

   function concatenate(string memory s1, string memory s2) public pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(s1, s2));
   }

   function showtest () external  view  returns(uint ){
        uint s = studuims[0].id ;
        return s ;
   }
}
```

Comment: i have the massage when try to call showtest function :     The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not formatted when pasted here, but I created the following sample which will help you to read struct from another contract. This is the contract which is holding the struct data:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Test {
    struct studuim  {
        string name;
        uint256 id;
    }
    
    studuim [] public studuims;
    
    function addStudium(string memory _name, uint256 _id) public {
        studuims.push(studuim(_name, _id));
    }
    
    function returnStadium(uint256 _index) public view returns(string memory, uint256) {
        return (studuims[_index].name, studuims[_index].id);
    }
}
```

And this is the second contract which is reading the structs data from the first contract:

```
contract ReadingContract {
    Test test;
    
    constructor (address _test_address) {
        test = Test(_test_address);
    }
    
    function getTestContractStadiums(uint256 _index) public view returns(string memory, uint256) {
        return test.returnStadium(_index);
    }
}
```

Solidity is still very primitive when it comes to reading lists of data, so you have to pass the index of the struct in order to return all the struct parameters. You cannot retrieve the full structs list.